# What is that syntax : $FilePath$ -t?

Tags: windows, npm, phpstorm

What is that syntax and how can I find the corresponding value in

> $FilePath$ -t

This is added as parameters in the PhpStorm IDE CSS comb installation.

Comment: `$FilePath$` is a macro that will be expanded to full file path when running the tool (see the answer). `-t` is csscomb cli option that enables the TTY mode - see  https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js/blob/dev/doc/usage-cli.md#options

Comment: Why does this need the Windows tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `$FilePath$` is macros in File Watcher/External Tools. It gets resolved to the actual value when file watcher gets executed.

You can check all of them and insert new ones by clicking on "Insert Macro..." button next to the input field (preview value for your current project/file is shown for most of them, excluding complex macro that can have additional parameters).

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.1/new-watcher-dialog.html

> Arguments are usually specified using macros, for example, **$FileName$** or **$FileNameWithoutExtension$**, that will be replaced with actual file names.
>   Type the macros manually or click **Insert Macro** and select the relevant pattern from the list in the **Macros** dialog that opens.

P.S. For the File Watcher, if you set "Show console" to be "Always", you will then be able to see the whole command that gets executed (when it gets executed, not before that).